# How to encode the result of a mathematical operation in JSON from Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to save the result of an addition in JSON format. I want as output something like that:

```
Result_0=[add,1,1,2]
```

but instead I have this result:

```
{Result_0=["add",1,1,null]}
```

I don't get why it read the result of the operation as null value. This is my code:

```
from Exercise_0 import *
import json

if __name__=="__main__":
    c= Calculator('Casio')
    d={}
    a=1
    b=1
    result=c.add(a,b)
    key="Result_0"
    d[key]=["add",1,1,result]
    print(json.dumps(d))
```

Exercise_0:

```
class Calculator():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name


    def add(self, number_1, number_2):
        print(f"{number_1}+{number_2}={number_1+number_2}")


    def sub(self, number_1,number_2):
        print(f"{number_1}-{number_2}={number_1-number_2}")

    def mul(self, number_1,number_2):
        print(f"{number_1}*{number_2}={number_1*number_2}")

    def div(self, number_1,number_2):   
        print(f"{number_1}/{number_2}={number_1/number_2}")
```

Comment: just saving in json format and displaying it as json output. No particular purpouse.

Comment: You mean _encode_? There's no encryption here.

Comment: It seems perfectly normal JSON output – those curly brackets are part of it. What has JSON to do with encryption? Are you sure you aren't looking for serialization instead?

Comment: Can you print out `result` just after when you calculate it?

Comment: There's your problem. `add()` (and all of your other operations) don't `return` anything. Hence `None` in Python, which becomes `null` in JavaScript. Replace `print(foo)` with `return foo`.

Comment: For usr2564301: Maybe it's serialization. The point is that I can't save the result of the operation as a number. It keeps saving it as a null value in json and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, either conceptually or practically

Comment: Like I said, you're not `return`ing anything. That's what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Chris, thank you! I didn't know about this, now I feel dumb ahah I tried to look on here for some similar question but not understanding the problem I couldn't find anything. Thank you again! Now it works

Comment: `import *` is bad practice.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change add() into:

```
def add(self, number_1, number_2):
        return number_1+number_2
```

And you will get:

> {"Result_0": ["add", 1, 1, 2]}

You should do the same for other functions as `sub`, `mul`... as well, so the result is returned back to the `result` variable which is later on used with the value of the function result. Something like:

```
import json

class Calculator():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

    def add(self, number_1, number_2):
        return number_1+number_2

    def sub(self, number_1, number_2):
        return number_1-number_2

    def mul(self, number_1, number_2):
        return number_1*number_2

    def div(self, number_1, number_2):   
        return number_1/number_2


if __name__=="__main__":
    c= Calculator('Casio')
    d={}
    a=3
    b=2

    key="Result_0"
    result=c.add(a,b)
    d[key]=["add",3,2,result]
    print(json.dumps(d))

    result=c.sub(a,b)
    d[key]=["sub",3,2,result]
    print(json.dumps(d))

    result=c.mul(a,b)
    d[key]=["mul",3,2,result]
    print(json.dumps(d))

    result=c.div(a,b)
    d[key]=["div",3,2,result]
    print(json.dumps(d))
```

Resulting in:

> ```
> {"Result_0": ["add", 3, 2, 5]}
> {"Result_0": ["sub", 3, 2, 1]}
> {"Result_0": ["mul", 3, 2, 6]}
> {"Result_0": ["div", 3, 2, 1.5]}
> ```